# WHMCS API error when calling "OpenTicket"

Tags: whmcs

I am trying to create a ticket via the WHMCS Api (latest version) using axios from my react app.
When I make the call, there are two calls from the client: one for the OPTIONS (CORS) and the second for the actual POST, with [all the the necessary fields](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/openticket/), however, I am getting two errors:

**1. Request one**:

```
Request URL: https://my-domain/includes/api.php?accesskey=<KEY>q&identifier=<ID>&secret<SECRET>&action=OpenTicket
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 62.*.*.*:443
```

Response:

```
result=error;message=An admin user is required
```

**2. Request 2**:

```
Request URL: https://my-domain/includes/api.php?accesskey=<KEY>q&identifier=<ID>&secret<SECRET>&action=OpenTicket
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 62.*.*.*:443
```

**Payload**:

```
{
admin: true
deptid: "1"
email: "something@mail.domain"
markdown: true
message: "test"
name: "text"
priority: "Medium"
responsetype: "json"
subject: "test"
}
```

**Response**:

```
result=error;message=Name and email address are required if not a client
```

JS code:

```
...
const ticketObject = {
    admin: true
    deptid: "1"
    email: "something@mail.domain"
    markdown: true
    message: "test"
    name: "text"
    priority: "Medium"
    responsetype: "json"
    subject: "test"
};

    const res = await axios.post(
      "https://my-domain/includes/api.php?accesskey=<KEY>q&identifier=<ID>&secret<SECRET>&action=OpenTicket",
      ticketObject
    );
...
```

Server details:

- OS: CentOS 7
- Webserver: Nginx (latest version) proxy_pass to httpd

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name my-domain www.my-domain;
    error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.error.log error;

    location / {

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/my-domain/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }


    # Check if the origin of th request
    set $cors '';

    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*\.proudtech\.ro?(:[0-9]+)?$)) {
    set $cors 'on';
    }

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    set $cors "${cors}_options";
    }

    # Allow CORS on preflight request
    if ($cors = 'on_options') {
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
    return 204;
    }

    # Proxy pass to upstream
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    # Allow CORS on other requests after returning from the upstreams
    if ($cors = 'on') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
    }

    proxy_pass      http://62.*.*.*:8080;
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/my-domain/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://62.*.*.*:8080;
    }


    include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.my-domain.conf*;

}

server {
    if ($host = my-domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      62.*.*.*:80;
    server_name my-domain www.my-domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

VirtualHost conf:
```

```
ServerName my-domain
ServerAlias www.my-domain
ServerAdmin info@my-domain
DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/my-domain/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/my-domain/cgi-bin/
Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/my-domain/stats/
Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/my-domain/document_errors/
#SuexecUserGroup admin admin
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.bytes bytes
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.log combined
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/my-domain.error.log
<Directory /home/admin/web/my-domain/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/my-domain/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
</Directory>
<Directory /home/admin/web/my-domain/stats>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid admin admin
    RGroups apache
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    AssignUserID admin admin
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/httpd.my-domain.conf*
```

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation about the OpenTicket API function: https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/openticket/

You shouldn't both use `admin` and `email`. Email should only be entered if it's a non-existing client that creates the ticket. You shouldn't use `name` either.

Comment: This is not the issue. The problem is that this only work when using UrlSearchParam() from js as the WHMCS api uses php//input to retrieve the request data.